# Drupal add link for maintenance page

Tags: drupal-7, admin

I try to add simple link for maintenance page.
So in first place a add "Custom Permissions" module and let all my "contributor" access to the maintenance page ...
But they don't have link ...

In my main module i add this

```
$items['admin/crisis'] = array(
    'title' => 'IsCrisis',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
    'page arguments' => array('admin/config/development/maintenance'),
    'access arguments' => array('access editor control panel'),
    'weight' => 50,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
);
```

with my administrator account i can see le link ! But contributor account can't ...
How to display this link for contributor ?

Comment: is your link giving any error in contributor account when accessed.

Comment: no error, work with my admin account , work with contributor account , juste not displayed ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem which you are facing can be solved by following steps below:

1. Changing the 'access arguments' to 'administer site configuration'.
2. Go to {your_domain}/admin/people/permissions and give the 'administer site configuration' permission to the required role who need to access the link 'admin/crisis'.
3. The user role with permission of 'administer site configuration' can only view this maintenance form.

Note: Only trusted roles can be given this permission.

Thanks